# Achieve Complex Animaton in IOS HomeScreen Widget. (Known to be achievable)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit, ios-animations

[image: a widget with an animation]
I am asking about how to achieve repetitive and smooth animation that looks like Lottie or gif in IOS widgets. I have attached the image as example. I KNOW many people say this cannot be done but clearly this app somehow did it against the restrictions of SwiftUI.

I have been trying for two days now and I'm dying to know how this is done. So far I tried TimelineView, wrapping UIViewController or UIView, displaying gif in Image(uiimage:), none of these worked. And I know there was this private api called _clockHandRotation used for rotation animation. But this is clearly something different.
(This is my first question, let me know if I did anything wrong)

Comment: Only possible via private API before iOS 17 you can look at WWDC videos for how to animate widgets iOS 17+

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.